# Is domain component in Active Directory the same with the domain my account is in?

Tags: active-directory

My account is in the `hc` domain. When I log into my computer, I will enter `hc\xxx` in the account name textbox. So I think my domain name is `hc`.

But when I try to explore the domain server, there is a lot of information that confuses me.

[image]

In the root of the node tree in the picture, I see it is `hc.cn`. What is this? Is it the domain name? If so, why do I use `hc\xxx` to log into my computer, not `hc.cn\xxx`? And also near the `hc.cn`, I see the [xxx.xxx.xxx], is it the domain controller that Active Directory explorer is connecting to?

In the second line, I see `DC=hc, DC=cn`. I am not very clear with domain component concepts. Does that mean cn is a big domain and hc is a sub domain of it? Here in `DC=hc`, is the `hc` the same with `hc\xxx`'s `hc`?

Comment: Hi Robin. I can see you were active recently and might have visited my answer. Is there anything in my answer about which you want further clarification? 

In the current state, it seems my answer hasn't helped much!

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. Actually I am googling some key words in your answer, such as NetBIOS, pre-windows 2000. I am a developer, not a OPS guy. Your answer really give me some clue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My account is in the hc domain. When I log into my computer, I will
>   enter hc\xxx in the account name textbox. So I think my domain name is
>   hc.

No, hc is the NetBIOS name of your domain. It is required for name resolution, and a bit older thing.

> In the root of the node tree in the picture, I see it is hc.cn. What
>   is this? Is it the domain name?

Yes. Based on your screenshot, `hc.cn` appears to be the domain name.

> If so, why do I use hc\xxx to log into my computer, not hc.cn\xxx?

This is called pre-Windows 2000 logon name.

> And also near the hc.cn, I see the [xxx.xxx.xxx], is it the domain
>   controller that Active Directory explorer is connecting to?

Yes, you're correct.

> In the second line, I see DC=hc, DC=cn. I am not very clear with
>   domain component concepts. Does that mean cn is a big domain and hc is
>   a sub domain of it?

This is the distinguished name representation of your domain (also called Base DN). Any domain name should have at least two words separated by a period (as per Microsoft's recommendation). Check the link about ["Naming conventions in Active Directory for computers, domains, sites, and OUs"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and) for additional information.

As I said, it is the DN representation of your domain. So, if your domain name is alpha.beta.gamma, then the DN for the same would be DC=alpha,DC=beta,DC=gamma.

> Here in DC=hc, is the hc the same with hc\xxx's hc?

Yes, relatively.

You can get the details of concepts/terms mentioned above doing few web search. If you require any help, please let me know.

Comment: By the way, what is the relationship between hc in "pre-Windows 2000 logon name hc\xxxx" and hc in domain hc.cn?

Comment: Your `hc` is NetBIOS name; `hc\xxxx` is pre-Windows 2000 logon name, and 
 `hc.cn` is domain name. NetBIOS name could have been "Theta" as well, for which the pre-Windows 2000 logon name would have changed to "Theta\xxxx", but the domain name still being "hc.cn". Hope it helps @RobinSun.

Comment: As you say, the NetBIOS name is changed to Theta. Then when I log on with Theta\xxxx, how does the system know which domain it  should connect to and validate the user?

Comment: @RobinSun - The domain controller(s) is(are) well aware of the NetBIOS name, as it has to be configured while setting up the domain! This might help you further -> http://smallcitydesign.com/netbios-name/